# Fill unbound variables by a range

Tags: prolog, logic, clpfd

lets say that L is `L = [[1,100,_], [200, _,94]].`
I have a code where I use

`append(List, L), L ins 1..90, .......`

`L ins 1..90` is false because there are elements which are not in the domain. But I want L ins 1..90 to only specify the unbound variables not the whole list. Is there a way for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
List = [[1,100,_], [200, _,94]],
append(List, L),
partition(ground, L, _, Unground),
Unground ins 1..90
```